# Python script to take multiple number of arguments from shell

Tags: python, getopt

I am trying to take multiple files as input from terminal. the input number may vary from atleast 1 to many. Here is the input for my program

```
F3.py -e <Energy cutoff> -i <inputfiles>
```

I want the parameter -i to take any number of values from 1 to multiple.e.g.

```
F3.py -e <Energy cutoff> -i file1 file2
F3.py -e <Energy cutoff> -i *.pdb
```

Right now it takes only the first file and then stops.
This is what I have so far:

```
def main(argv):
try:
    opts,args=getopt.getopt(argv,"he:i:")
    for opt,arg in opts:
        if opt=="-h":
            print 'F3.py -e <Energy cutoff> -i <inputfiles>'
            sys.exit()
        elif opt == "-e":
            E_Cut=float(arg)
            print 'minimum energy=',E_Cut
        elif opt == "-i":
            files.append(arg)
            print files
    funtction(files)
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print 'F3.py -e <Energy cutoff> -i <inputfiles>'
    sys.exit(2)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest reading about Python's [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) module, which is in general easier to work with than `getopt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the @larsks suggestion, the next snippet should work for your use case:

```
import argparse 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input values', nargs='+', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

print args
```

**kwargs explanation:**

- `nargs` allows you to parse the values as a list, so you can iterate over using something like: `for i in args.input`.
- `required` makes this argument mandatory, so you must add at least one element

By using the argparse module you also got the -h option to describe your params. So try using:

```
$ python P3.py -h
usage: a.py [-h] -i INPUT [INPUT ...]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT [INPUT ...], --input INPUT [INPUT ...]
                        Input values


$ python P3.py -i file1 file2 filen
Namespace(input=['file1', 'file2', 'filen'])
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. One question though, why does it show even the required options under the "optional arguments when prompted -h"

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `getopt` you will have to combine multiple argument with delimeter other than space like `,` and then modify your code accordingly like this

```
import getopt
import sys

try:
    opts,args=getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"he:i:")
    for opt,arg in opts:
        if opt=="-h":
            print 'F3.py -e <Energy cutoff> -i <inputfiles>'
            sys.exit()
        elif opt == "-e":
            E_Cut=float(arg)
            print 'minimum energy=',E_Cut
        elif opt == "-i":
            files = arg.split(",")
            print files
    #funtction(files)
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print 'F3.py -e <Energy cutoff> -i <inputfiles>'
    sys.exit(2)
```

When you run this you will get output

```
>main.py -e 20 -i file1,file2
minimum energy= 20.0
['file1', 'file2']
```

**NOTE**
I have commented your function call and removed unwrap your code from main function, you can redo these things in your code it will not change your result.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this would be difficult when using all the files in a directory for input.

Comment: Well yes getopt has its own limitation and argparse is definetly better :)